# Seeking simple sample mapcache.xml file that works with mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, ubuntu, mapcache

I have a functioning mapserver installation runing on Ubuntu 14.04 and it's working fine.  However, I would like to up the performance by putting mapcache in front of it.

I've installed mapcache, but I can't seem to create a valid mapcache.xml file.

I've found a number of 'complete' examples online, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around all of the details.

Can someone point me to a minimal mapcache.xml file that simply forwards GetMap requests to mapserver and caches the resulting tiles?

That would at least help get me started.

Comment: I second this post, I've been also looking for a simple example to do this, I want to use CGI directly.

Comment: And not through WMS? Does WMS already work for you with the mapcache.xml that comes with the sources?

Comment: well, I think it could be through WMS, the problem if I'm right is that through WMS I would have to add all the details of my WMS layers in the mapcache.xml, and using CGI would be simpler (ie. mapcache fetches all layers details directly from the main MAP file), am I right? does it work that way?

Comment: So where do you stand now? Have you had a try with the demo configuration that installs by default and is also available from https://github.com/mapserver/mapcache/blob/master/mapcache.xml?

Comment: The direct use of mapfile is still undocumented as in http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2013-September/075293.html and I think it is an experimental feature and need to be activated when building mapcache. Have you made your own build from the sources and with the USE_MAPSERVER flag? Otherwise I fear that you are wasting your time.

Comment: Indeed I use Ubuntu here, so just got mapcache from the Ubuntugis repo. I also checked the link you suggested, at least someone is working succesfully with cgi, that's is what I prefer. In any case, if you post a clear, detailed and very useful answer about using mapcache through eg. WMS I think it will win if it works well.

Comment: Once MapCache is installed you should see a demo at address `http://localhost/mapcache/demo`(or in whatever address your server has) with a preconfigured services. Doesn't the demo work for you? For me it works and the config file it is using is the one I already mentioned: https://github.com/mapserver/mapcache/blob/master/mapcache.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cache tiles from the backend WMS without having to know the layer names beforehand use either "combined_mirror" or "split_mirror" mode.

This doesn't seem to be properly documented, but it is mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/mapserver/mapcache/issues/34)

"combined_mirror" makes a tileset for each combination of layers encountered. "split_mirror" will make a tileset for each layer and then assemble these tiles.

The configuration shown in the issue (note "combined_mirror" and no wms layers defined):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mapcache mode="combined_mirror">
   <cache name="disk" type="disk">
      <base>/tmp</base>
      <symlink_blank/>
   </cache>

   <source name="vmap0" type="wms">
      <getmap>
         <params>
            <FORMAT>image/jpeg</FORMAT>
         </params>
      </getmap>

      <http>
         <url>http://www2.dmsolutions.ca/cgi-bin/mswms_gmap</url>
      </http>
   </source>

   <tileset name="mirror">
      <source>vmap0</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid>WGS84</grid>
      <grid>g</grid>
      <format>JPEG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>3600</expires>
   </tileset>


   <default_format>JPEG</default_format>

   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
      <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
      <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
      <format>JPEG</format>
      <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
      <forwarding_rule name="catch all">
            <http>
               <url>http://www2.dmsolutions.ca/cgi-bin/mswms_gmap</url>
            </http>
      </forwarding_rule>
   </service>
   <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

   <errors>report</errors>
   <lock_dir>/tmp</lock_dir>

</mapcache>
```